# Is there a term that describes reducing a person's identity to certain characteristics?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, nouns, terminology, psychology

Is there a term that describes reducing a person's identity to certain characteristics, behaviours or traits that are not physical? The term should have a negative connotation. I've heard the expression "putting people in boxes", but it's not just about stereotyping, but about making those qualities their whole identity. For example, when we focus on someone's flaws, or one flaw, and don't see anything else.

here's how the sentence would go: "The issue with all the previous thoughts is that they come from a self-centred, judgemental, WORD attitude".

Comment: You could *objectify* someone, and that's insulting if you reduce them to their looks or their shape.

Comment: Obviously, it's "characterizing".

Comment: Why doesn't *stereotyping* fit? You seem to be talking about reducing somebody to a single characteristic.

Comment: This is what natal horoscopes and Myers-Briggs tests do. They categorize personalities with regard to their own sets of categories.

Comment: The _attitude_ in your example would be "_ignorant_" or "_narrow-minded_", and they could all replace "WORD". But that doesn't address what you've described in the body of the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be called **typecasting** someone. The term originally comes from acting, but it is often used metaphorically; [TfD defines it as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/typecasting)

> To perceive or represent [someone] in reductive or stereotyped ways

Comment: Thank you! Is there an adjective version of this word?

Comment: @MariaCW There is not a related adjective, unfortunately; *typecast* is just a verb.

Comment: Typecast is an adjective: OED **type-cast, adj**. 1. Formed into type for printing. 1876 *This hammer..carries at its extremity a type~cast letter.* -- 2. Of an actor, etc.: that has been type-cast (see type-cast v.); identified with a particular kind of part. **Also transferred and in extended use.** -- 1982    *One gets the feeling she's typecast in her show.*

Comment: @MariaCW _typecasting_ is an adjective that fits in your example sentence

Comment: I'm not sure the past participle in this sense has really been promoted to an adjective: "she was very typecast" sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @alphabet I think that's just more that it's not comparable. It sounds no worse to me than "very past" or "very identical."

Comment: What advantage does the domain-specific *typecasting* offer over *stereotyping*?

Answer (score 20):

> Is there a term that describes **reducing** a person's identity to certain characteristics, behaviours or traits that are not physical?

One easy answer would be *reductionist* (adjective).
[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/reductionist) defines it as:

> 2 simplistic to the point of minimizing, obscuring, or distorting a complex idea, issue, or condition: 
> *Both stories describe the same reality, but your reductionist version fails to capture the full truth.*

Your example would be:

> The issue with all the previous thoughts is that they come from a self-centred, judgemental, **reductionist** attitude.

Comment: I think this is the best fit in the OP's sentence, being an adjective which describes a person doing the thing.

Comment: "reductive" is also possible

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Yeah, I thought about "reductionist", "reductionistic" and "reductive". But I think I'm more comfortable with the first one. That said, I'd like to know why and where the other two might be used instead.

Answer (score 12):

You are probably looking for ***[caricature](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/caricature):***

> a picture, description, etc., ludicrously exaggerating the peculiarities or defects of persons or things.

(Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 5):

The term **pigeonhole** fits what you are looking for. The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pigeonhole) has some definitions for this:

> to have an often unfair idea of what type someone or something is
>
> to put someone or something into a group or type, often unfairly
>
> to form a fixed and often unfair idea of what someone or something is like

They also provide some examples:

> He was pigeonholed early on in his career as a gospel singer.
>
> We decided to drop the .com in our name because we didn't want to be pigeonholed as an internet company.

Answer (score 2):

"The issue with all the previous thoughts is that they come from a self-centred, judgemental, **labelling** attitude".

---

The [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/104693?rskey=diWweE&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) indicates that one of the meanings of **labelling** covers this particular meaning.

> 4. transitive. **To apply a classifying word or phrase** to (a person or thing); to categorize (a person or thing) using a particular word or phrase (sometimes with the implication that **such categorization is inaccurate, simplistic, or restrictive**). Chiefly with as or complement specifying the classifying word or phrase. Cf. label n.1 9.

One example given demonstrates the usage particularly well :

1881   M. Arnold Byron in Macmillan's Mag. Mar. 376/1   **It would be most unjust to label Byron..as a rhetorician only**

Answer (score 1):

### Essentialism

Essentialist thinking says that 'if you are a member of this group, you have all the traits that I associate with that group'.

"The issue with all the previous thoughts is that they come from a self-centred, judgemental, and essentialist attitude".

Or, as Dr. Susan Gelmen [says](https://www.apa.org/science/about/psa/2005/05/gelman#:%7E:text=Essentialism%20is%20the%20view%20that,(2005%2C%20May%201).):

> Essentialism is the view that certain categories (e.g., women, racial groups, dinosaurs, original Picasso artwork) have an underlying reality or true nature that one cannot observe directly. Furthermore, this underlying reality (or "essence") is thought to give objects their identity, and to be responsible for similarities that category members share.

Answer (score 0):

**superficial** (*adj*)

- A twofer meaning not only shallow but also perceptually shallow.
- A would-be casting agent if not for lack of character and depth perception.
- By [Power of Positivity](https://www.powerofpositivity.com/signs-of-superficial-person/):

> When “sizing up” a superficial person, you won’t see much depth.
>
> —"10 Signs You’re Dealing With A Superficial Person"

But who needs 10? It's a catch-22. It's like irony without the presents.

[Superficial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superficial) (2a of 2, M-W):

> concerned only with the obvious or apparent : SHALLOW

A deep definition of [shallow](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shallow) (3a of 4, M-W):

> penetrating only the easily or quickly perceived
> *shallow* generalizations